# c++ seekg() read specific number

Tags: c++

I have a text file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I want to read a specific number by using seekg()

```
ifstream fr("duomenys.txt");
fr.seekg(2,ios::beg);
int n;
fr >> n;
cout << n;
```

If I set position to 1, 2 or 3, readed number is correct, but using other positions, it returns earlier numbers, for example positions 3 and 4 both return 3, positions 5 and 6 both return 4. If I'm right, this is happening because of the spaces between numbers, but I don't get it, why if position is 3, it returns number 3, not 2 as expected because of the space between 2 and 3? And a question, how should I make my function, that I can get specific number from the file using his position? I'm trying to do like an array, which is in a file, for example, A[i] returns item from array at index i, so my function(i) should return item at index i from file.

Comment: It works fine, if it's numbers from 0 to 10, but with bigger numbers it doesn't because of the fact that they are from 2 or more characters, any ideas how to deal with that problem?

Comment: @PaulR `seekg` isn't defined for text files unless the offset is 0, or a value returned from an earlier call to `tellg`.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can't.  In a text file, the
arguement to `seekg` must be a value returned from a previous
`tellg`, with a few exceptions to allow you to seek to the
beginning or the end of the file.  Seeking to position 5, for
example, has no meaning.

If you open the file in binary, you can do a little bit more,
but the seek position will still be in bytes; you have to know
the exact position of each number in the file.  In the file
you've presented, the positions would be 0, 2, 4... etc.  But
this assumes exactly one digit per number, and exactly one space
separating them, which may not be realistic.

For small data sets like yours (in the example, at least), the
obvious solution is just to read all of the data into an
`std::vector`, and index into that.  For very large data sets:
the file must be written expressedly to support the reads, in
binary mode, with a fixed number of characters per number
(including any separators).  You could then seek to `i * n`,
where `i` is the position you want, and `n` the number of characters
per number.  But again, only in binary mode, both reading and
writing.